# Is there a less trickier way to solve this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential equation:
$$ y^3 dy+(x + y^2)dx = 0$$
**Solution**:
The following solution uses the substitution $y^2=tx$.
$$y^3\frac{dy}{dx}+x+y^2=0\tag1$$
Differentiating $y^2 = tx$,
$$ 2y\frac {dy}{dx}= t + x\frac{dt}{dx}$$
Now substituting in **(1)**,
$$tx\ (t + x\frac{dt}{dx})+2(x+tx)=0$$
$$t^2x+tx^2\frac{dt}{dx}+ 2x + 2tx=0 $$
$$2tx\ dx + t^2x\ dx + 2x\ dx+tx^2\ dt=0$$
$$x\ dx\ (t^2 + 2t + 2)=-tx^2\  dt$$
$$\int{\frac{1}{x}}dx= \int{\frac{-t}{t^2+2t+2}}dt$$
$$lnx=\int{\frac{-t-1}{t^2+2t+2}}dt + \int{\frac{1}{t^2+2t+2}dt}$$
$$lnx=\int{\frac{-t-1}{(t+1)^2+1}}dt+\int{\frac{1}{(t+1)^2+1}}dt$$
$$lnx=-\frac{1}{2}ln[(t+1)^2+1]+ \arctan(\frac{y^2}{x}+1)$$
$$lnx=-\frac{1}{2}ln[(\frac{y^2}{x}+1)^2+1)]+ \arctan(\frac{y^2}{x}+1)$$
I have the following questions:
1) How did the person who solved this problem get the idea of substituting
$y=tx^2$ ? This substitution doesn't seem to be obvious.
2) Is there any other method (without using the above substitution) to solve this problem, in a less trickier manner?

Comment: Solving nonlinear differential equations usually boils down to finding the right trick. Whoever solved this one probably tried lots of tricks and different substitutions until they found this one, which worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substitution presented does seem somewhat unmotivated.

Given

\begin{equation}
(x+y^2)dx+y^3dy=0
\end{equation}

one would be inclined to first try the substitution $x=uy^2$ so that the $y^2$ might factor out of the first term.

This gives $dx=y^2du+2uy\,dy$ yielding after a bit of algebra the separable equation

\begin{equation}
y^4(u+1)du+y^3(2u^2+2u+1)dy=0
\end{equation}

Separation gives

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{u+1}{2u^2+2u+1}\,du+\dfrac{1}{y}\,dy=0
\end{equation}

which is straightforward, perhaps aided by the substitution $v=2u+1$ with the first integral partitioned into its logarithmic and inverse tangent parts.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This one definitely looks more logical than substituting y^2 = tx.

Answer (score 0):

$y^3~dy+(x+y^2)~dx=0$

$y^3\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-x-y^2$

Let $u=y^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dx}=2y\dfrac{dy}{dx}$

$\therefore\dfrac{y^2}{2}\dfrac{du}{dx}=-x-y^2$

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=-\dfrac{2x}{y^2}-2$

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=-\dfrac{2x}{u}-2$

Luckily this becomes a first-order homogeneous ODE.